# How to have a game object prefab with mutiple sprites?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using https://www.raywenderlich.com/269-how-to-create-a-tower-defense-game-in-unity-part-1 for some help with programming and in the article the site mentions a prefab that is a game object with mutiple sprites and shooting animations as their childern, but I've not been able to figure out how to do that.

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: can you add the complete link?

Comment: @Chico3001 just made the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A given `GameObject` can only have one `SpriteRenderer` component. However, you can have multiple `GameObjects` each with their own `SpriteRenderer`, each the child of a parent `GameObject`. You can affect the sprites' render order by changing the [`OrderInLayer` field](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html), or by using [layers more generally](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html),